# java creates .nfsXXXX files in logs ... why?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, nfs

I want file logs to be turned off keeping only console logs for my java spring application. 
I changed logback.xml config to be set to consoleappender and logging.properties config without AsyncFileHandler.

It is now generating localhost_access_log which is configured in server.xml and some .nfsXXXXX files which actually contains logs but not sure why it creates those ?

logging.properties

```
.handlers =  java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################


java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################


# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE
```

Can anyone help with .nfs log files files ? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It's not Java, it's the NFS client: https://serverfault.com/questions/201294/nfsxxxx-files-appearing-what-are-those